# Excel sheet merging different column

Tags: excel, dataframe

Having an excel file as shown as below:

First sheet:

```
| Animal_with_age|
|----------------|
| Animal-Dog123L |
| at-cat234L     |
|  MS-Donkey12   |
|  occoco98L     |
| Ms-dog donkeyone|
```

Second sheet:-

```
| Animal         |
|--------------  |
| Dog            |
| CAT            |
| Donkey         |
|  coco          |
| dog donkeyone  |
```

I need the output as below:

sheet 1:

```
| Animal_with_age|Animal|
|----------------|------|
| Animal-Dog123L |Dog   |
| at-cat234L     |Cat   |
|  MS-Donkey12   |Donkey|
|  occoco98L     |coco  |
|Ms-dog donkeyone| dogdonkeyone|
```

Is that possible? Is that possible if i convert to dataframe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using **Filter, INDEX-MATCH & SEARCH** formulas, we can do **full to partial** string matching...

```
=INDEX(FILTER(Sheet2!$A$2:$A$6,ISNUMBER(SEARCH(Sheet2!$A$2:$A$6,Sheet1!A2)),0),MATCH(MAX(LEN(FILTER(Sheet2!$A$2:$A$6,ISNUMBER(SEARCH(Sheet2!$A$2:$A$6,Sheet1!A2)),0))),LEN(FILTER(Sheet2!$A$2:$A$6,ISNUMBER(SEARCH(Sheet2!$A$2:$A$6,Sheet1!A2)),0)),0))
```

**Output of sheet1 -> Paste formula in sheet1 cell b2 & drag till last row;**

[image]

Hope this Helps...

Comment: can you help me,where i need to paste this equation? on sheet number1?

Comment: Sheet2 actually... On b2 cell.. then drag till last row

Comment: I need the output on sheet1, In the shown format..can you help me?

Comment: Yes Nikita... Let me edit the answer... it's doable using xlookup

Comment: Hi sacchin...i added a new value at the end of excel. Its not working,its only mapp to dog.

Comment: Sure... give me sometime.. will edit the formula... I think can do using filter & index-match formulas... but formula will become very complex & long... let me see